# Push text file into android Emulator

Tags: android

I need to push a text file into android emulator in location SD card. I tried using DDMS
and referring this video: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipRke1P4rIc`. But after pushing its not showing in emulator. why is that? Please help me.

Comment: did u add this permission <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: if you see the file in ddms file folder then restart emulator and you can see the file there

Comment: have to give SD card size while created a AVD??

Comment: Sometime it fails to push the file because of some error, Eclipse might showing a error to you in the console if you have done like create SD card

Comment: yah. but why it is not inserting into the sd card? Is it related with permissions??

Comment: @androidsuckzzz Any error in your eclipse console when you try to push the file ?

Comment: Your code  can you show us?

Comment: @MengMeng please refer http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipRke1P4rIc. I did the same.

Comment: @Williams Error is transfer Error read only file system. Please help me guys. How to sort it out?

Comment: @androidsuckzzz Sorry .Youtube is blocked in my company

Comment: @MengMeng Error is transfer Error read only file system.

Comment: Could you open your adb shell . and run "ls -l" .Make sure you \sdcard is exist and writeable

Comment: @MengMeng I am new to android my location of of sdk is : C:\Users\sambsa\android-sdks\tools. How I will open adb shell. I am new to android. Please help me dude.

Comment: run "C:\Users\sambsa\android-sdks\tools\adb shell" then "ls -l"

Comment: Got error The system can not find path specified.

Comment: let us gtalk xinmeng2011@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

> Error is transfer Error read only file system. Please help me guys. How to sort it out?

It seems you are pushing the file where you don't have write access. So you change the permission like so

```
adb shell
su 
mount -o rw,remount rootfs / 
chmod 777 /mnt/sdcard
```

Comment: Iam using windows. I am new to android. Can you please tell how can I open ADB shell. Sorry for this stupid comment, but im new to this.

Comment: Go here like this cd C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130729\sdk\platform-tools in your cmd then execute the commands

Comment: Error no such path found.

Comment: yup that I understand. but which path I need to put. ma android sda and android installation paths are below: C:\Users\sambsa\android-sdks and C:\Users\sambsa\.android

Comment: Finally got it. after entering that its showing: root@generic:/# . What to do? I it ready to use?